# How to fix a parent div containing floating relative children?

Tags: html, css, css-position

I'm trying to give my header a fixed position so the header is always visible when scrolling the page. The header (parent div) has two children div inside. When I position the parent div to fixed, the parent div height is set to 0 and it ignores its children div. How do I make this happen?

```css
/*HEADER ELEMENTS*////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#header_container{
    min-width:240px;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
position:fixed;

}

#header_container:after { 
    content: " "; 
    display: block; 
    clear: both;
} 

#left_header{
float:left;
width:42%;
display:block;
background:white;
padding:1%;
padding-left:7%;
position:relative;
}

.logo_link{
    padding:1%;
    margin:1%;
}


.lh_link{
   padding:1%;
   margin:1%;
}

.lh_link:hover{
  border: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
  
}

#right_header{
    float:right;
width:42%;
padding:1%;
padding-right:7%;
background:white;
text-align:right;
position:relative;
}

.rh_link{
   padding:1%;
   margin:1%;
}

.rh_link:hover{
  border: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
  
}



/**/
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">


<div id="header_container" role="header">
    
    
    
    <div id="left_header">
        
        <a class="logo_link" href="">I am the logo</a><br><br>

        <a class="lh_link" href="">Welcome here</a>
        
        <a class="lh_link" href="">Articles</a>
    
        <a class="lh_link" href="">Join</a>
    
    </div>
    
    
    
    <div id="right_header">
        
        <br><br>
    
        <a class="rh_link" href="">About</a>
        
        <a class="rh_link" href="">Contact</a>
        
        <a class="rh_link" href="">Our Team</a>
        
        <a class="rh_link" href="">Services</a>
        
    </div>
    
    
    
</div>
```

Comment: Clearing issue, but seems to work fine, since you are already using the :after trick to clear the floats.  What browser are you using where it fails ?

Comment: working fine for me ..

Comment: @HaukurHaf: I'm using Firefox but I also tested in Chrome.

Comment: Ok, like I said, seems to work fine.  Not sure why it does not work for you.  Try adding overflow:auto; to your #header_container.

Comment: Oh dear... Well firstly `/*HEADER ELEMENTS*////////////////////////////////////////////////////` is not valid CSS as a comment must be fully within `/* */`.

Comment: @SimonEast: lol I know, I was just playing around a bit. It is not official. But thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason adding `.clearfix` to `#header_container` (parent div) did the trick, everything else did not work for me:

Markup

```
<div id="header_container" class="clearfix" role="header">
```

Css

```
#header_container{
    min-width:240px;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}

.clearfix:after {
     display: block;
     content: " ";
     clear: both;
     height: 0;
     }
.clearfix { 
    display: inline-block; 
    position:fixed; 
    min-width:240px;
    width:100%;}

.clearfix { display: block; }


#left_header{
float:left;
width:42%;
background:white;
padding:1%;
padding-left:7%;
position:relative;
}

#right_header{
float:right;
width:42%;
padding:1%;
padding-right:7%;
background:white;
text-align:right;
position:relative;
}
```

Comment: Yes, do you understand what a clearfix does?  It ensures that a parent block fully wraps around floated children.  Without it, floated children can expand outside the parent.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#header_container{
  min-width:240px;
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
  position:fixed;

  float: left;
}
```

This is a clearing issue: because you are floating your contained divs to the left, your container div needs to compensate for their floating. You can either use the CSS above or apply `clear: both;` to your contained divs. Either of these methods should have the same result.